# How are the immediately-declared constraint-expressions of type-constraints combined?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, c++23

If `C` is a concept, are the following constructs equivalent?

```cpp
template <C A, C B>
```

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B>
requires C<A> && C<B>
```

In other words, are all the [immediately-declared](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#def:constraint,immediately-declared) *[constraint-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#nt:constraint-expression)s* associated with a *[type-constraint](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#nt:type-constraint)* combined via conjunction (`&&`)?

I was unable to find any wording which confirms this.
Note that this nuance is extremely important, because if a conjunction is used, then a template with `C A` and `C B` parameters would be more constrained than another with only `C<A>` or `<B>` constraints. If there is no conjunction, then neither is more constrained than the other.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr#decl-3.3  ?

Comment: @ildjarn yes, that answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are combined to form the *associated constraints* by conjunction in a specified order which includes the  type constraints introduced in the template parameter list in order of their appearance per [[temp.constr.decl]/3.3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.constr.decl#3.3.1).

So the associated constraints are the same in both of your declarations: `C<A> && C<B>`